# Will my site load faster if the image is on the other domain?

Tags: performance, image, browser

I'm wondering will my site perform loading faster if the images that I use to upload it on my wordpress `wp-content-uploads` now it's going to be store in a totally different domain (which I've control) that I installed the image upload services like flickr or any website that use for uploading service.

Because when I perform the test on http://gtmetrix.com I have like 93% for page speed and only  72% for Yslow

http://gtmetrix.com/reports/applesiam.com/rF12jFmv

I really think that my page load slow somehow because it says

```
Page load time: 14.54s
Total page size: 4.35MB
Total number of requests: 169
```

Thanks

Comment: Really sorry I thought I did go to wordpress.stackexchange.com. Didn't mean to post here :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably.

Most browsers throttles the number of simultaneous requests to each domain, so using multiple domains allows browsers to issue more requests at the same time. This should lead to a faster rendering of the page.

However, if obtaining an image from your domain is significantly slower than from the original one, than the change will not improve the load speed.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer here. and what if it's the same domain but I use it in the different directory? will that somehow help?

Comment: No - different directory will not help as it's the domain that browsers look at.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think hosting your images on another hostname is going to make that much difference to your sites performance.

The site is slow because the pages are too large, and have many third party components - this waterfall will give you some idea -

http://www.webpagetest.org/result/120411_BG_b66024d1dda2429676d1e646e4b23a86/

Look at how you can reduce the number of components.

Updated:

Seriously look at the number of components and where they come from - out of **195** resources on the page only **31** come from applesiam.com

Answer (score 0):

It will be faster. However the number of simultaneous connections from a browser to a domain is usually limited to 4-6.
You can circumvent this limit by creating a bunch of subdomain alias for your static content, all pointing to the same IP. Like

```
s[1-5].yourdomain.com -> same IP
```

Then access your images from different aldomains and the browser will load them parallel.

**Update**:

Looking at your site more thoroughly, responses from your site are slow.

Requesting `http://applesiam.com/wp-content/themes/volt/images/social_sprite_32.png` gives back HTTP 304 (Not modified) but that took 824 ms (tested with Firebug). It should be around 100 ms from the other side of the globe.

I made some ApacheBench tests for this image.

10 concurrent request:

```
» ab -n 10 -c 10 http://applesiam.com/wp-content/themes/volt/images/social_sprite_32.png

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%   1683
  66%   1685
  75%   1701
  80%   1710
  90%   1710
  95%   1710
  98%   1710
  99%   1710
 100%   1710 (longest request)
```

20 concurrent request:

```
» ab -n 20 -c 20 http://applesiam.com/wp-content/themes/volt/images/social_sprite_32.png

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%   2272
  66%   2899
  75%   2910
  80%   2974
  90%   2982
  95%   2985
  98%   2985
  99%   2985
 100%   2985 (longest request)
```

Doubling the number of simultaneous requests almost doubled the response time, which means your server cannot handle a moderate number of requests. You should check your server for bottlenecks (CPU, RAM, network, web sever config).

Comment: 2 was the limit for IE6 (and is what the HTTP RFC specifies) but most browsers support 4 or 6 connections per hostname these days (see http://www.browserscope.org/?category=network&v=top)

Comment: True, Firefox sets it to 6. Updated the answer.